# AttributeError: ‘Prediction’ object has no attribute ‘label’

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, roboflow

I have code for recognizing road signs. Everything is implemented on Raspberry Pi 4. I'm using Python 3.9 and roboflow 1.1.12. The code itself is below:

```
import requests
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera import PiCamera
from roboflow import Roboflow

# Инициализируем клиент Roboflow
rf = Roboflow(api_key="API_key")
project = rf.workspace().project("project_name")
model = project.version(1).model

# Инициализация камеры
camera = PiCamera()

# Загружаем классы для вывода результатов
classes = ['Stop', '60 km/h', '40 km/h', 'Forward']

# Захватываем видеопоток с камеры
camera.start_preview()
while True:
  # Снимаем фрейм с камеры и сохраняем его
  camera.capture('frame.jpg')

  # Загружаем фрейм и изменяем его размер
  image = cv2.imread('frame.jpg')
  image = cv2.resize(image, (300, 300))

  # Конвертируем изображение в формат RGB
  image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

  # Предсказываем на изображении
  result = model.predict(image_rgb)

  # Извлекаем информацию о дорожных знаках из результата
  detections = result.predictions

  for detection in detections:
      class_name = detection.label
      confidence = detection.confidence
      box = detection.bounding_box


  # Выводим результаты на экран
  cv2.imshow("Road Sign Detection", image)

  # Выход из цикла по нажатию клавиши 'q'
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break

# Закрываем окна и освобождаем ресурсы камеры
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
camera.stop_preview()
```

But I get an error and I don't understand which correct attribute is needed here.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/rasberrypi/Desktop/Проект 3/ai17.py", 
    line 38, in <module> class_name = detection.label 
    AttributeError: 'Prediction' object has no attribute 'label'
```

The error itself occurs when I show the desired road sign to the camera (that is, at the recognition stage)

I tried different attributes, like class/classes/class_id, and I have no idea what I need here in this block.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you are doing with ```class_name = detection.label``` when each ```detection``` is a Prediction class (https://github.com/roboflow/roboflow-python/blob/main/roboflow/util/prediction.py)  which has no label.

Comment: Some of your indentation is clearly wrong, but what's less clear is how it ought to be indented. Don't make us guess; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: Fixed formating. Sorry for that.  "Please clarify what you are doing with class_name = detection.label when each detection is a Prediction class (github.com/roboflow/roboflow-python/blob/main/roboflow/util/…) which has no label. " - Here i try to  to call the class name that I declared at the beginning. It seems to output 'Stop' when the Stop sign appears

Comment: It is Bullseye or BookwormÉ

Comment: Actually it is Bullseye

Answer (score 0):

Jackob, it looks like you forgot to call `.json()` before trying to access predictions. [Roboflow-python documentation](https://github.com/roboflow/roboflow-python#quickstart) shows an example how to use it. Below I will provide some of the code from there.

```
predictions = model.predict(img_url, hosted=True).json()
print(predictions)
```

YOUR code could look something like this

```
import json

# ...

# Предсказываем на изображении
result = model.predict(image_rgb).json()

# Извлекаем информацию о дорожных знаках из результата
detections = json.loads(result)["predictions"]

for detection in detections:
    class_name = detection["class"]
    confidence = detection["confidence"]
    # some output here?
```

Keep in mind that there may be a situation where your roboflow model detect nothing on the picture. Hence the `predictions` list will be empty. You may have to do some additional checking for this.

You can easily try any model in action and see what data it outputs. Go to [Roboflow Universe](https://universe.roboflow.com/), search for "traffic signs" or "road signs". Next, select the model with which you want to test road signs recognition. I would focus on the number of images on which the model has been trained (the bigger the better). Next, click "Try Pre-Trained Model" and you get running in the cloud roboflow model (something like Hugging Face Spaces). Select an image and see what result the model produces. For example, I tried doing the steps I wrote above and got the following JSON, see my attached screenshot below. Such JSON you can get in your program if you adjust your code like I suggest you above.

[image: Roboflow Universe playground]